# FTP Streaming and custom Splitting large CSV file using camel

Tags: csv, ftp, stream, apache-camel

Iam using camel 2.17,I need to stream and split large csv file by custom logic with same policy number and group it with 2 policy no together.Below is the sample csv and iam expecting it to spilt as three as below.can it be achieved using the inbuilt split functionality of camel?

CSV File:

```
POLICYNO;ID;NAME;LOB;TYPE
152024;1278;ABCGmbH;liability; 
152024;1278;ABCGmbH;hull; 
152025;1271;ACB  SE;personal accident;M-HLTA
152025;1271;ACB  SE;liability;M-HLTA
152025;1271;ACB  SE;liability (AV 52);M-HLTA
152025;1271;ACB  SE;hull;M-HLTA
152025;1271;ACB  SE;hull / war;M-HLTA
152026;1239;FUND AG;liability;D-ABCD
152026;1239;FUND AG;liability (AV 52);D-ABCD
152027;1261;FIXTURE;personal accident; 
152027;1261;FIXTURE;liability; 
152027;1261;FIXTURE;hull; 
152027;1261;FIXTURE;hull / war; 
152028;1241;JET;personal accident;OK-KANMANI
152028;1241;JET;liability;OK-KANMANI
152028;1241;JET;hull;OK-KANMANI
152028;1241;JET;hull / war;OK-KANMANI
```

Split 1 :

```
152024;1278;ABCGmbH;liability; 
152024;1278;ABCGmbH;hull; 
152025;1271;ACB  SE;personal accident;M-HLTA
152025;1271;ACB  SE;liability;M-HLTA
152025;1271;ACB  SE;liability (AV 52);M-HLTA
152025;1271;ACB  SE;hull;M-HLTA
152025;1271;ACB  SE;hull / war;M-HLTA
```

Split 2

```
152026;1239;FUND AG;liability;D-ABCD
152026;1239;FUND AG;liability (AV 52);D-ABCD
152027;1261;FIXTURE;personal accident; 
152027;1261;FIXTURE;liability; 
152027;1261;FIXTURE;hull; 
152027;1261;FIXTURE;hull / war;
```

Split 3

```
152028;1241;JET;personal accident;OK-KANMANI
152028;1241;JET;liability;OK-KANMANI
152028;1241;JET;hull;OK-KANMANI
152028;1241;JET;hull / war;OK-KANMANI
```

Comment: I highly doubt any tool can do this split for you. Even IBM IIB will find it hard to split this without some custom code. In this case how do you even know what value the next row has without looking?  Essentially you need to write a customer splitter for this.

Comment: Is there any examples that I can refer to implement custom splitter with streaming..?

Comment: I would look at the resequencer pattern to create data sets first then split the sets out.

Comment: I'm curious if you ever found a solution for this.  Was there a way to group by just one policy number instead of 2?